# Can a Windows 8 HTML/JS app run as a website?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am a Web developer getting into the new Windows 8 store track by making Javascript Windows 8 apps.

I'm interested to know, that if I make a Windows 8 store app in Javascript, if this is easily deploy-able as a hosted website, to run in browsers.

i.e. Can I without making significant changes to my app, host it with IIS and when people browse to it, act much like it would as the original app?

I would follow normal HTML5 browser guidelines and not use Win8 shortcuts, like skipping extra audio/video tracks. Opening the generated default.htm seems blank, so definitely doesn't work out of the box, but i'm wondering if there is a library that can hook up and run most of the stuff, considering it to be a simple app.

TIA

Comment: I don't think so, they have some JS SDK defined on W8

Comment: I don't think so either, but it would be a shame, since you are still writing pure web code...

Comment: You're not writing pure web code. In fact, anything that interfaces with the Windows Runtime is not available in browsers on the web.

Comment: @Joey, yeah that figures. I'm wondering if there's a library that can close those gaps when taking the code for the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows expose some of the Windows Runtime feature thru Javascript. You cannot use this kind of feature in the WebApp.

But if you design your application with different layer it should be easy to exclude the Windows Runtime featue when you deploy it to other browsers.

The pure Javascript will of course run in every browser.

I'm not 100% but I guess that if you use something like

```
var object = WinJS.UI.Animation.createAddToListAnimation(added, affected);
```

It is bundled to the *hosted enviroment* for the app. It could not be reused if Chrome should render the page.

One approch is to create a wrapper for a UI compontent, so for example you have YourApp.CreateTab, and that implements the WinJS.UI or for another browser it will use jQuery UI for creating the tab.

Comment: So you're saying I won't be able to carry over the same look and feel and that part i'll have to re-code for my web? Naturally I can isolate all BL etc.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting approach. My question doesn't ask "how" but mostly "is it doable?" so in essence you've answered that.